# Attempting to compare values in an array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am attempting to write a program that compares values in two arrays. The user enters in 6 numbers which are stored in an array. Then I randomly create 6 numbers and store them in another array. I then sort the arrays and convert them into strings and then compare the strings to see if the values are the same in both arrays. If they do not match, in my while loop I attempt to randomly create 6 numbers and store them in the 2nd array until the arrays match. However at the moment when i try to echo the amount of times it took it just says '0' times.

Here is the code i'm using.

```
<?php 

    $number1 = $_POST['number1'];
    $number2 = $_POST['number2'];
    $number3 = $_POST['number3'];
    $number4 = $_POST['number4'];
    $number5 = $_POST['number5'];
    $number6 = $_POST['number6'];


$userArray = array($number1, $number2, $number3, $number4, $number5, $number6);


// mix and max numbers that can be used with th lottery
$min = 0;
$max = 9;
// random number between 0 and 1 simulating lottery

    $lotNumber1 = rand ($min, $max);
    $lotNumber2 = rand ($min, $max);
    $lotNumber3 = rand ($min, $max);
    $lotNumber4 = rand ($min, $max);
    $lotNumber5 = rand ($min, $max);
    $lotNumber6 = rand ($min, $max);

$lotArray = array($lotNumber1, $lotNumber2, $lotNumber3, $lotNumber4, $lotNumber5, $lotNumber6);

asort($userArray);
asort($lotArray);

$userString = implode($lotArray, "_"); 
$lotString = implode($lotArray, "_");


$i = 0;

while($lotString != $userString) {
   $i ++;

     $lotNumber1 = rand ($min, $max);
    $lotNumber2 = rand ($min, $max);
    $lotNumber3 = rand ($min, $max);
    $lotNumber4 = rand ($min, $max);
    $lotNumber5 = rand ($min, $max);
    $lotNumber6 = rand ($min, $max);

    $lotArray = array($lotNumber1, $lotNumber2,             $lotNumber3, $lotNumber4, $lotNumber5, $lotNumber6);
    asort($lotArray);

    $lotString = implode($lotArray, "_");

}

echo "YOU WON it took".$i."times";


?>
```

Comment: Wouldn't `array_diff()` be the easier approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reasons why it always takes zero attempts is because you have an error when you initially compute the two strings to compare!

Change these two lines

```
$userString = implode($lotArray, "_"); 
$lotString = implode($lotArray, "_");
```

to

```
$userString = implode($userArray, "_"); 
$lotString = implode($lotArray, "_");
```

Such things happen, don't worry :-)